# Filter email with wild card

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

From the documentation found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb738155(v=EXCHG.150).aspx).

The property `EmailAddresses` can be filtered with a wildcard. However when using a wildcard the search turns up no results.  My code is:

```
Get-DistributionGroup -Filter { EmailAddresses -like "email*" }
```

I can find the group when using:

```
Get-DistributionGroup -Filter { EmailAddresses -eq "email@domain.com" }
```

But if I use a wildcard which the documentation says is supported, nothing is found.

I understand I can accomplish this functionality by piping the command into a `Where-Object` or `ForEach-Object` but with thousands of objects this would take a lot more time than using `-Filter`, so I am just wondering if it is indeed possible to filter `EmailAddresses` with a wild card.

I also know that I can use `PrimarySmtpAddress` or `WindowsEmailAddress` to filter but I'm more looking to be able to search by any email address under the `EmailAddresses` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to include the prefix. After doing so it worked perfectly.

```
Get-DistributionGroup -Filter { EmailAddresses -like "smtp:email*" }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use -Filter as a parameter, you're not using standard PowerShell filtering (which is where the -Like comparison operator comes from).  Instead, you're stuck using the provider's native filtering capabilities.  These often use really weird syntax that is different from the way PowerShell does things.

Reading the full breakdown on which comparison operators are allowed, I see that Emailaddresses does allow for wildcard...so I think this is broken.  Sorry man, it should be working[, based on what I see here.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb738155(v=EXCHG.150).aspx)